# C# Adding txt file names to a combo box

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

How would I add txt files in a certaint directory to a combo box, but only their names.
Like lets say there is a folder called "Data"
and inside there is 3 txt files named
Names
Food
Beverages

Now I want to add they're names to a combo box. How would I do that?

Comment: Can you put what you try?

Comment: Can you please put some code to understand??

Answer (score 3):

You need to use   `DirectoryInfo("pathToDirectory")` and `GetFiles("*.txt")` from this path. Next array FileInfo add as DataSource to ComboBox. This is sample.

```
DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\Mateusz\Desktop\test");//Assuming Test is your Folder
FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles("*.txt"); //Getting Text files

comboBox1.DataSource = Files;
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

This code was tested and working very well.
[image]

Comment: Why was this downvoted? This is a really nice and clean answer for a simple problem. You have my upvote.

Comment: Someone can't appreciate others time.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you any text files in 'path', remove the directory and extension and add to combobox:

```
string[] textFiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.txt");
foreach (string file in textFiles)
{
    // Remove the directory from the string
    string filename = file.Substring(file.LastIndexOf(@"\") + 1);
    // Remove the extension from the filename
    string name = filename.Substring(0, filename.LastIndexOf(@"."));
    // Add the name to the combo box
    combobox1.Items.Add(name);
}
```

Comment: Consider using some System.IO utilites that already implement the removal of the directory, etc.

Comment: Just giving a different solution. Definitely not as nice as M.Wisnicki's solution.